# HTTP POST is not working from Java

Tags: java, apache, http, servlets, post

I am trying to do an http post. Same code was working.But now it is not hitting my servlet now, but giving http response code 200. From browser same url is hitting the servlet. Is there anything that restricting my post?. Please help me on it. Sorry for bad english.

```
int timeout=3000;
String url="http://localhost:8020/WiCodeDynamic/WiCode?json=";
String requestUrl="{\"vspCredentials\":{\"id\":\"TET\",\"password\":\"test\"}}";
URL x = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)x.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
//;charset=utf-8
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
bw.write(requestUrl);
bw.flush();

int resp_code = connection.getResponseCode();
String resp_msg = connection.getResponseMessage();

System.out.println("resp_code="+resp_code);
System.out.println("resp_msg="+resp_msg);
```

brs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a minor mistake. Move the `json=` from the end of your URL to the beginning of your POST request (`requestUrl`) and you should be fine.

Also I suggest you use `URLEncoder.encode` to escape the string you are transfering properly.

Comment: i have moved.but now i got null on retrieving the parameter json in my servlet. Earlier it was empty. Any more changes?

Comment: Did you use URLEncoder.encode? If you did not it will fail.

Comment: Yes, i used it.URLEncoder.encode(requestUrl, "UTF-8");

Comment: Only the part after your `json=` must go into the URLEncoder. If you send in all the encoder will escape the `=`

Comment: Thanks..since i was putting content type as json. I should have written as stream directly without parameter= in request url. I commented the content type and got it worked.